# Configure Varnish on Ubuntu LAMP for multiple websites on single web server instance

Tags: varnish, lamp

I am hosting multiple websites in a single server instance. Now, I want to configure **Varnish Cache on LAMP (Ubuntu server)**. Is it possible to configure Varnish Cache for each and every website within the same server instance?

If possible, how can we achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Varnish is a transparent cache. It will work for multiple websites in a single instance without any issue.

If your many websites are using the same platform, i.e. Wordpress, you are just fine with single VCL file configuration.

If your many websites are using different CMS, and need to have different handling / cache logic per-site, you have to make use of include files as outlined in [this article](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish/varnish-virtual-hosts).